# Number theory and primitive roots

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to find the primitive roots of 35 . What i know is that we find the euler totient of 35 which is 24 and we check the divisors of 24 to be the powers but it was a great time consuming ... how can we reduce the time and find them more easilly ? 
 Help or hints will ve highly appreciated

Comment: Carmichael function $\lambda(35)=12<\phi(35)$

Answer (score 2):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic iff $n=2,4,p^k,2p^k$ with $p\geq 3$ prime number. This is not your case.

Comment: Aaaaaa ..... :)